# From where I can download Adobe AEM Quickstart jar file to start practicing on it?

Tags: adobe, aem

I am a developer. I want to learn Adobe Experience Manager. That's why I need to setup it locally to start learning. But I can't because I have not found any link to download AEM quickstart jar file. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 4):

You can't download AEM like you can download WordPress or Drupal. You can try contacting Adobe on the [Marketing Cloud website](http://www.adobe.com/marketing-cloud/enterprise-content-management.html) although I don't know what their response will be. If you attend an [Adobe Training Services class for AEM](http://training.adobe.com/training/courses.html#product=adobe-cq) you will walk away with an AEM jar and a developer's license.

In the meantime, AEM is based off a lot of open source technology. You can download and learn [Apache Sling](https://sling.apache.org/), [Apache Jackrabbit](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/) and [Apache Felix](http://felix.apache.org/).

Answer (score 3):

You will need to get with an Adobe sales person to get a trial/demo version of Adobe Experience Manager. Use phone number on the bottom of the AEM page on the Adobe site: **http://www.adobe.com/products/request-consultation/marketing-cloud.html?s_osc=70114000002JNwKAAW&s_iid=70114000002JHs3AAG**

Please have a look at same kind of Questions on Adobe AEM Forums:
Link:- http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__axbl-any_trial_versionof.html

I hope this will help you.

Thanks and Regards
Kautuk Sahni

Answer (score 1):

If you're working for an organisation that has AEM licenses available (a client or a partner of Adobe's), you can find the quickstart JAR, as well as feature packs, hotfixes and service packs on the Software Distribution Portal. See https://experience.adobe.com/#/downloads/content/software-distribution/en/aem.html

You'll need an Adobe login belonging to an organisation that has access to AEM, though.

One thing that may be confusing is that you won't find every individual version available as a quickstart. There's usually a reasonably recent quickstart JAR available, and service packs that need to be installed on top of it. For example, at the time of writing, I could download `cq-quickstart-6.5.8.jar`. If I wanted SP 11 or SP 12, I had to install `aem-service-pkg-6.5.11-1.0.zip` or `aem-service-pkg-6.5.12.0.zip` as CRX package. There's no need to install intermediate versions. You should be fine just getting the zip with the exact SP version you want to use.